# OpenLayers Select Feature with control points

Tags: openlayers, gml, geojson

I have a OpenLayers.Layer.GML layer build with GeoJSON data given by MapFish.
When I select his features control points are displayed and they let me edit the shape of the features. Well I don't want them! And I don't know how they appeared or why.
There must be some setting in the control, in the layer or in the map that produce this.

Here's a screenshot

[image: feature selected with control points]

The code I use to generate the control is this:

```
_selectFeatureControl = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(
    _activeLayer,
    {
        clickout: true, 
        toggle: true,
        multiple: false, 
        hover: false,
        toggleKey: "ctrlKey", // ctrl key removes from selection
        multipleKey: "shiftKey" // shift key adds to selection
    }
 );
```

The layer generation code is:

```
layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.GML(
   displayName,
   url,
   {
       format: OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON,
       isBaseLayer: false,
       visibility: true,

       styleMap: styleMap,

       projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326")
   }
);
```

Thanks every one!

Comment: so you're not adding a `ModifyFeature` anywhere in your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
var controls = map.getControlsByClass('OpenLayers.Control.ModifyFeature');
for(var i=0;i<controls.length;i++){
    controls[i].deactivate();
    controls[i].destroy();
}
```

Comment: Oh yeah! It worked! :) Thanks a lot!!

I was using GeoExt to display a window with the feature' attributes, I guess the component I use automatically adds the modify feature control...

Comment: In that case, you should dig into the GeoExt documentation to try and find it. I consider my solution a hack.